# Chaning wp_links_pages to "Next Page" and "Previous Page" buttons?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

in my wordpress single.php i have `<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'pearl' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>`

I would like for this to be "Next Page" and "Single Page" buttons instead of what it currently is which is `Pages: 1 2 3 4`

I have tried searching, but I think it would change from using `wp_link_pages` completely I'm just not sure what it changes to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
```

Thanks